# ResourceExhaustedError Tensorflow, can I use Ram

Tags: python, tensorflow, ram, convolution

I'm working with tensorflow, in particular I'm trying to use multiple convolutional layers. The problem is that I get always a `ResourceExhaustedError`, so I can't train my network with a big batch. 
My gpu has 2 GB of ram. Is there a way to use also the ram  of my notebook?

Comment: you can use CPU ram, but GPU with smaller batch will be faster

Comment: what is the best choice between using a bigger batch (using cpu ram) and using smaller batch (gpu ram) ? I mean: how this will influence the performance of my network?

Comment: Net Performance (accuracy)  doesn't change but training is fastest if everything is on gpu

Comment: You can try playing the game of manually placing your operations on CPU or GPU (using `with tf.device('/cpu:0')`) if you can identify the specific operations that need a lot of memory, but as @yaroslav-bulatov mentioned, the overhead of moving data between GPU and CPU might eat up the benefit of using GPU.